# Java Convert List<String> to List<Object>

Tags: java

I've two classess CsvRead and MyOwnClass.

In CsvRead I've a method public static List getDataFromCsv(); It returns list of all data. And this data I want to take in another method in class MyOwnClass and return there as list of objects of My OwnClass

It looks like this:

```
List<String> dataFromCsv = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And in another class, I want to convert it to `List<Object>` of my class.

```
private static List<String> getDataFromCsvClass = new ArrayList<String>();
getDataFromCsvClass = CsvReader.getAllCsvData(filename);
String name = dataFromCsv[0];
String surname = dataFromCsv[1];
String birth = dataFromCsv[2];
```

I want to return `new MyOwnClass(name, surname, birth);`

MY ERROR: array required but List found: String name = allData[0]; etc

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: One of my method in CsvClass return list of String with all csv data. And in another class I want to take this data , assign it to List<String> and next return list of objects my ownClass

Comment: It's included inside method which take csv data from file in another class

Comment: Do you means that every 3 strings contain name,surname,birth? In other words, data[3] contains the name of the second element?

Comment: I've two classess  CsvRead and MyOwnClass.

Comment: In CsvRead I've a method public static List<String> getDataFromCsv();
It returns list<string> of all data.   And this data I want to take in another method in class  MyOwnClass and return there as list of objects of My OwnClass

Comment: First of all, you'll be better off returning `List<MyOwnClass>`. Second, I still don't see what is stopping you from doing what you want. If there is an error, you should add it to question.

Comment: @Smithy and what is format of String that you are in List<String> ? is that containts (name,surname,birth)????

Comment: So how can I parse  List<String> allData =new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: To list of objects MyOwnClass which returns List<Object>

Comment: MY ERROR:  array required but List<String> found:
String name = allData[0]; etc.

Comment: @Smithy can you reply to our answer  above plz !! and whats version of java that you use !!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `method` to convert a `String` to `MyOwnClass` and use `stream` to map the elements, e.g.:

```
public static MyOwnClass convertToObject(String element){
    String[] tokens = element.split(",");
    return new MyOwnClass(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2]);
}

//code to convert
List<String> dataFromCsv = new ArrayList<String>();
List<MyOwnClass> list = dataFromCsv.stream()
.map(e -> convertToObject(e))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

However, this may not work if let's say `name` or `surname` contains comma. In which case, I would recommend having a look at `OpenCSV` library and [this](http://howtodoinjava.com/3rd-party/parse-read-write-csv-files-opencsv-tutorial/) example of how to read csv into objects.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that the list contains the name, surname and birth in every group of 3 strings (i.e., the elements on index 0, 3, 6, 9 etc. contain the name), you might try the following:

```
public List<MyOwnClass> convertCsvData(List<String> csv_data)
{
  // Initialize result
  List<MyOwnClass> result;
  result = new ArrayList<MyOwnClass>();

  // Parse data
  int    counter;
  String name;
  String surname;
  String birth;
  for (counter = 0; counter < csv_data.size(); counter += 3)
  {
    name = csv_data.get(counter);
    surname = csv_data.get(counter + 1);
    birth = csv_data.get(counter + 2);
    result.add(new MyOwnClass(name, surname, birth));
  }

  // Done
  return (result);

} // convertCsvData
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this :

```
private static MyOwnClass toMyOwnClass(String str){
 String[] object= str.split(",");
 return new MyOwnClass(object[0], object[1], object[2]);
 }



 List<String> dataFromCsv = new ArrayList<String>(); 
 List<MyOwnClass> list = new ArrayList<>();

 for(String string : dataFromCsv ){
     if(StringUtils.isNoneEmpty(string)){
     list.add(toMyOwnClass(string));
   }
 }
```

And then you return your list